# Is there a notion of an almost measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if the set $\{x:f(x)<a\}$ is Lebesgue measurable for all real numbers $a$.  But my question is, what if something slightly weaker is true?  What if $\{x:f(x)<a\}$ is only Lebesgue measurable for almost all real numbers $a$?  That is, what if the set of all real numbers $a$ such that $\{x:f(x)<a\}$ is not Lebesgue measurable has Lebesgue measure $0$?  Then what can we say about $f$?

Can we say that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, or what?

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is complete, in the sense that it contains all subsets of sets of measure $0$. Thus “measurable’ or “equal almost everywhere to a measurable function” are the same.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I took that part out.  By the way, is "equal to a measurable function except on a set of measure epsilon, for every epsilon" equivalent to measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{x :f(x) < a\}$ is measurable for almost every real number $a$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure). Then the set of such $a$ must be dense in the real line, thus for any real number $y$ we can find a sequence of such $a$, say $(a_n)$, such that $a_n \to x$ monotonically from below. Then
$$ \{x : f(x) < y\} = \cup_n \{x : f(x) < a_n\}$$
and hence is measurable as a countable union of measurable sets. Thus your definition of 'almost measurable' is just equivalent to the usual definition.